# Checkin data with history timestamp

Tags: svn

I want to put some source code to Subversion repository. The source code is in timestamped directories with the date as timestamp:

```
+ 2008-07-23-1324
+---+ folder A
    +-- fileA.c
+---+ folder B
    +-- fileB.c
+ 2008-08-12-1026
+---+ folder A
    +-- fileA.c
+---+ folder B
    +-- fileB.c
    +-- fileC.c
```

Now I want to create a repository with the check-in dates 2008-07-23-1234 and so on. This would move the ugly storage in timestamped directories to a version control system.

I know there is Git, that do this. But it shall be Subversion.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can import these directories one by one into your SVN repository. Make sure that you import them in chronological order (older timestamps first).

Then modify the [`svn:date` unversioned property (aka revision property)](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/props/#svn.advanced.props.ref.unversioned) associated with these commits.

You can use the [`svn propset --revprop`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/propset/) command to modify revision properties. If you are on Windows, TortoiseSVN has a nice GUI for this.

Note that before modifying revision properties you have to enable their modifications in your repository. You need to create the [pre-revprop-change hook](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/reposhooks/pre-revprop-change/) in the repository that exits with zero value (`exit 0`). Otherwise, changes to revision properties will be denied.